# matplotlib - No xlabel and xticks for twinx axes in subploted figures

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

What I want to do is a 2x2 diagrams in a subplot. Then, for each figure, I am going to use two y-axes. Therefore, I used twinx() method for each diagram. The problem as you see in the figure I shared is that it does not show xlabel and xticks for first row. For the second row, everything is fine. I have specified the problem in red font in the figure ("No xlabel and xticks!!!").

Each diagram has its own x-axis and y-axis and there is no sharing in that.

I have tweaked this code a lot and narrowed down the problem maker. It is because I use twinx() in upper rows. If I try to remove the secondary y axis, everything goes back to normal and the xlabel and ylabel for upper rows are shown correctly.

I don't know what is the problem!

This is the code I am working on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO(u"""     amount     price
A     40929   4066443
B     93904   9611272
C    188349  19360005
D    248438  24335536
E    205622  18888604
F    140173  12580900
G     76243   6751731
H     36859   3418329
I     29304   2758928
J     39768   3201269
K     30350   2867059""")

df = pd.read_csv(s, index_col=0, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

fig = plt.figure() 

ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.plot([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
ax_22.plot([1.0/x for x in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]])
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX2 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX2 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX2_Twin Y Lablel")


ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(223, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.plot([100, 300, 500, 700, 900])
ax_22.plot([x*x for x in [100, 300, 500, 700, 900]])
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX3 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX3 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX3_Twin Y Lablel")




ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(224, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX4 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX4 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX4_Twin Y Lablel")






ax = fig.add_subplot(221, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax2 = ax.twinx() 
width = 0.4
df.amount.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1, sharex=False, sharey=False)
df.price.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0, sharex=False, sharey=False)

ax.set_xlabel("Alphabets")
ax.set_ylabel('Amount')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')



plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8, hspace=0.8)
plt.savefig("t1.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

It generates following figure:

[image: output figure that I get from above code in python]

**EDITED:**

Thanks for the answers. However, my problem still exists when using Pandas in plotting diagrams. I opened a new question. Please take a look at it:

[matplotlib - pandas - no xlabel and xticks for twinx axes in subploted figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249393/matplotlib-pandas-no-xlabel-and-xticks-for-twinx-axes-in-subploted-figures)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you provided seems to produce the desired result.

[image: test run]

That makes me think that there is an issue with your console or matplotlib version - perhaps you can provide more information on how you are running the code.

I would recommend moving the `ax.set_xlabel` before `twinx` such as:

```
ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharex=None, sharey=None)
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX2 X Lablel")
ax_2.plot([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])

# Becomes...

ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharex=None, sharey=None)
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX2 X Lablel")
ax_2.plot([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
```

**EDIT** I would suggest using [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/gridspec.html) instead. See the below working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gspec
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
gs.update(hspace=0.7, wspace=0.7)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 1])


x1 = np.linspace(1,10,10)

ax1.plot(x1, x1**2)
ax1.set_xlabel('ax1 x')
ax1_2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1_2.plot(x1, x1**3)
ax1_2.set_ylabel('ax1_2 y')
ax1.set_ylabel('ax1 y')

# To save time I left the other cells blank, but it should work fine.

plt.show()
```

The above produces this:

[image: gridspec example]

Comment: Thanks Oniow. Even with the change you mentioned, no changes in the figure!
I am running my script on my Mac with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. 
Python: 2.7.11 (Compiled with GCC 4.4.7)
Matplotlib: 1.5.1

And, I am using Anaconda 2.4.0 as the package manager for my Python packages.

Comment: Did you change my code in any way? I am asking this because I need to generate the diagram and I want to know whether I made a mistake or not. Does any of above system configurations that I mentioned differ from yours? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello Millad - I was able to produce that plot using Python 3.4 and Matplotlib 1.5.0, using Anaconda as well. I made no changes to your code to get the desired result. It could be a python 3 vs. 2 thing - but I doubt it. What interface are you using? Are you saving the figure directly or outputting it to something like Ipython console?

Comment: In any case, I would suggest using [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/gridspec.html) instead. I have had much better luck with it when I have encountered similar problems. See my edited response.

Comment: Thanks @Oniow. :) I really appreciate it. `gridspec` seems to work perfectly on my Python 2.7, which I think is the source of the problem since you mentioned you are using Python 3. I am using Python _rawly_, so no IPython, no other fancy stuff :). And, I am also seeing this behavior on both the file I saved and the output window of `plt.show()`. I used your code and it worked on my machine for all 4 diagrams and for all axes that I wanted :). I accepted your answer as the solution but since I am not _experienced_ _enough_ from stackoverflow perspective, it may not show as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I approach issues like this one. First try to isolate the issue by reducing your code to a minimum. For instance, this code shows the same problem:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(212)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image: wrong plot]

Now we can see two things:

1. If I had made a mistake in just 5 lines of code it should be easy to find (at least easier than with the original code). Since I cannot find any mistakes I guess this is a bug in pandas or matplotlib. From the comments it could be a regression introduced in matplotlib 1.5.1.
2. There are two unusual things in this code:

   - The lower plot is created before the upper plot.
   - The dataframe is plotted in the primary axes after the twin axes is created.

Unusual things are more likely to trigger hidden bugs in the underlying libraries, so better avoid them if possible. Now let's see what happens if we create the subplots in the usual top-down order:

```
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)
fig.add_subplot(212)
```

[image: correct plot]

It seems to work, so let's try the same with the original code:

```
fig = plt.figure() 

ax = fig.add_subplot(221, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax2 = ax.twinx() 
width = 0.4
df.amount.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=1, sharex=False, sharey=False)
df.price.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0, sharex=False, sharey=False)

ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.plot([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
ax_22.plot([1.0/x for x in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]])
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX2 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX2 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX2_Twin Y Lablel")

ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(223, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.plot([100, 300, 500, 700, 900])
ax_22.plot([x*x for x in [100, 300, 500, 700, 900]])
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX3 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX3 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX3_Twin Y Lablel")

ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(224, sharex=None, sharey=None) 
ax_22 = ax_2.twinx()
ax_2.set_xlabel("AX4 X Lablel")
ax_2.set_ylabel("AX4 Y Lablel")
ax_22.set_ylabel("AX4_Twin Y Lablel")

ax.set_xlabel("Alphabets")
ax.set_ylabel('Amount')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8, hspace=0.8)
plt.savefig("t1.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: problem solved]

So problem solved (at least for me) via a workaround. An actual fix would be better but perfect is the enemy of good and now the subplots are created in a more logical order, which improves readability.

Comment: Oh my God. I am confused! It didn't work previously but it works fine right now! I think it might be due to the upgrade that I did on my Python packages (matplotlib and pandas). I also should mention that the reason I moved down the code that generates my upper plot, it was because it didn't work and I thought maybe it is some kinda of bug that this moving-down change will help with that. However, I really appreciate your time and effort (I have also accepted your answer).

Comment: If you define "ax3 = fig.add_subplot(212)" and call "pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax3)" the x-axis of ax still vanishes (?).

Comment: @Pat I do not know where you want to add that code but I encourage you to try by yourself.