# x-ticks disappear when plotting on subplots sharing x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This happens when I try to plot a line and an area on the same subplot. I found the my x-ticks disappear after I call ay=ax.twinx() and plot on ay.

Here's my code that causes this error.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=[12,12])
data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,2,4]])
ix = np.unravel_index(0, axes.shape)
ax=axes[ix]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
ax2=ax.twinx()
data.plot(ax=ax,color=['navy','red'])
ax2.plot(y.values, linewidth=2.0)
```

[image: x-ticks-disappear]

As you can see, the x-ticks disappear.
However, if you continue plotting, you can find the last subplot isn't affected.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=[12,12])
data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,2,4]])
ix = np.unravel_index(0, axes.shape)
ax=axes[ix]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
ax2=ax.twinx()
data.plot(ax=ax,color=['navy','red'])
ax2.plot(y.values, linewidth=2.0)
ix = np.unravel_index(1, axes.shape)
ax=axes[ix]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
ax2=ax.twinx()
data.plot(ax=ax,color=['navy','red'])
ax2.plot(y.values, linewidth=2.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Basically move `ax2 = ax.twinx()` _after_ you plot any data on `ax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options. One is based on the answer to this question: [matplotlib - pandas - No xlabel and xticks for twinx axes in subploted figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249393/matplotlib-pandas-no-xlabel-and-xticks-for-twinx-axes-in-subploted-figures)
which is to reverse the order of plotting. First plot to the two subplots, then create the twin axes for both.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,2,4]])

ax=axes[0]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
data.plot(ax=ax)

ax3=axes[1]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
data.plot(ax=ax3)

ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(y.values)
ax4=ax3.twinx()
ax4.plot(y.values)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now sometimes the above may not be an option, so the second possible solution would be to set the ticks visible again after the complete plot has been generated.

```
[t.set_visible(True) for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,2,4]])

ax=axes[0]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
ax2=ax.twinx()
data.plot(ax=ax)
ax2.plot(y.values)

ax3=axes[1]
y=pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:,0]-data.iloc[:,1])
ax4=ax3.twinx()
data.plot(ax=ax3)
ax4.plot(y.values)

[t.set_visible(True) for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: Since this only happens for pandas plots, I would guess that the pandas plotting wrapper for some reason thinks it needs to set the ticks invisible. Do you need to know the exact position in the pandas code where this goes wrong?